# How two computer sync to read data?

Tags: layer1

Recently I try to understand how data is transferred. So as far as i know, digital data can be transferred in the form of voltage from one computer to another through a wire.

But I don't understand how the transmitter computer and receiver computer can align. Say from the transmitter computer, it transfers voltage in frequency A, how can the receiver computer know this frequency? And even it knows, how to make sure the frequency is always aligned? Seems small shift can result in a wrong signals interpretation when accumulate.

Please help.

Comment: Look up "Clock Recovery" for discussions of how the receiver recovers the clock signal. Phase-locked loops are a key component for aligning the frequencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good question but not easily answered.

Generally, the transmitter's clock needs to be known and synchronized to by the receiver as you've pointed out. There are two basic methods for transmitting the clock:

- explicit, on a separate wire/channel (common for parallel transmissions)
- embedded - the clock signal is combined with the user data and recovered by the receiver (common for serial transmissions, especially for networking protocols)

An embedded clock can be very simple, e.g. with 10 Mbit/s Ethernet which uses *Manchester code* which basically modulates the clock with the user data: a `1` bit is transmitted as *low-high* and a `0` bit as *high-low*. This ensures a voltage/polarity change within each bit and makes clock recovery easy. In terms of bandwidth, it's very wasteful however - the transmitted bit rate is doubled for 50% overhead.

More efficient line codes are 8b/10b with two bits overhead for eight user bits (20% overhead) used with Gigabit Ethernet, and 64b/66b with just 3% overhead used with 10G Ethernet and faster.

Note that slow serial links can also use an 'agreed' bit rate that is simply known on each side. These links resynchronize on certain extraneous bits as @Almeidajoao has explained.

The clock provides *bit synchronization*. You also need *word synchronization* - find out where a word (usually a byte/octet) starts. With Ethernet, that is accomplished by the *start frame delimiter* SFD. The *preamble* in front of the SFD just alternates bits - `10101010 10101010 10101010 10101010 10101010 10101010 10101010`, ensuring clock synchronization, and is followed by the SFD `10101011` which signals the start of the first octet of an Ethernet frame.

Of course, there are many more ways to do it that could fill a book.

Comment: this answer really helps a lot. Do you have any book/video recommendation on this topic?

Comment: Sorry, resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help]. But if you're especially interested in Ethernet, the [IEEE 802.3 standard](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68) details the methods mentioned above (free after registration).